# Pin Callout Button Missing

Tags: ios, mapkit

I am using the following code to create my pin annotation callout, but my Detail Disclosure Button and my custom image do not show up. It must have something to do with `if([annotation isKindOfClass:[CustomAnnotation class]])` but I don't know what. What am I doing wrong here?

```
    - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    {
        return nil;
    }


    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[CustomAnnotation class]]) 

    {


        MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"CustomAnnotation"];

        if(annotationView == nil)
        {
            MKPinAnnotationView *customPinView =  [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"CustomAnnotation"];

            if([[customPinView.annotation title] isEqualToString:@"HQ"])
        {
            customPinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;


        }
        else
        {

            customPinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
        }

            customPinView.canShowCallout = YES;
            customPinView.animatesDrop = YES;

            UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
            [rightButton addTarget:nil action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            customPinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

        return customPinView;
    }
        else
        {
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        }
        return annotationView;
    }

        return nil;

}
```

Comment: is this being called      - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapVieviewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation

Comment: Yes, it is being called...

Comment: is annotationView returning nil?

Comment: My "if(annotationView == nil)" is not being called...

Answer (score 0):

Ah! I had catched your mistake .

```
if(annotationView == nil)
    {
         MKPinAnnotationView *customPinView =  [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]  initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"CustomAnnotation"];
    }// YOU ARE MISSING THIS BRACKET
```

if its nil it will get allocated and other things we want as usual.

Comment: Thanks for trying... that wasn't it. The bracket produces multiple errors in xcode...

Comment: Ok, I was able to fix it. In my NSUserDefaults, I forgot to match X *annotation1 =[[X alloc] init]; where "X" is my CustomAnnotation class.

Comment: may I clear it  for return customPinView;
    }//REMOVE THIS BRACKET